# How to use command line commands using drupal

Tags: php, drupal, terminal, vlc

I have a cloud server and i am running drupal 7 in it.
For some reason i have to do live video recording using VLC player on the server side.
I can do this running command line commands. 
But i was wondering if i could provide the client a web page in drupal in which 
the client could add the live video url and when it clicks submit my command line command
runs in the server terminal... something like that 
Please tell me if it is possible or not 
Any Leads / Links on this will be highly appreciated 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The Drupal parts is actually the easiest one. You will need to [create a custom module](https://drupal.org/node/361112) to implement [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) to provides a page with your form (build using the [Form API](https://drupal.org/node/751826))

```
function MODULE_menu() {
  return array(
    'encode_video' => array(
      'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
      'page arguments' => array('MODULE_encode_video_form'),
      'access arguments' => 'encode video'
    )
  );
}

function MODULE_encode_video_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form = array(
    'video_url' => array(
      '#type' => 'textfield', 
      '#title' => t('Video URL'), 
      '#size' => 80, 
      '#required' => TRUE,
    ),
    'submit' =>  array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Encode'),
    ),
  );
  return $form;
}

function MODULE_encode_video_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  // Validate and sanitize $form_state['values']['video_url'] here...
}

function MODULE_encode_video_form_submit($form, $form_state) {
  $url = $form_state['values']['video_url'];
  // Start video encoding here...
}
```

Encoding the video is the hardest part. Any method used to directly start a video encoding process from PHP must be carefully written. For instance, it has to handle process management to avoid overcharging the server with too many encoding. It must also ensure the process is properly launched in the background to avoid blocking the PHP process (to avoid timeout). A probably better solution, would be to enqueue encoding using some sort of background process manager. [Gearman](http://gearman.org/) may be a easy and clean solution here. It will also allow you to write your video encoding process in a separated language more suited to long running video encoding. There is a, currently in development, [Gearman integration module](https://drupal.org/project/gearman) to help its usage in Drupal, but it is not required.

Comment: Hey pierre, i got the drupal part working and in the submit hook i am adding this line of code shell_exec(" vlc -I rc \"http://hqxe.88safe.com/videostream.cgi?user=admin&pwd=&resolution=32&rate=6\" --sout '#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,vb=1024,acodec=mp4a,ab=256}:standard{mux=mp4,dst=/Users/abhishek/Desktop/output451.mp4,access=file}'");     I am running this drupal module on my localhost but can not get it to create a file on desktop. While if i do same command on terminal it works

Comment: if i type vlc in command line then the vlc player is launched and now if i type $output = shell_exec("vlc 2>&1"); print_r(''.$output); i get sh: vlc command not found

Comment: As I said, the encoding part is the hardest part. vlc is probably not in the PATH for the shell_exec() environment. Running commands from PHP is no as easy and straightforward as running them from a terminal. You should really look for a solution that allow you to asynchronously dispatch the encoding to a separated daemonized process.

Answer (score 0):

`exec` and `shell_exec` will help you get started.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

They allow you to execute any linux command from command line.

BE CAREFULLL!!!  Make sure that you are not dynamically creating a command from a string.  This could open you up to maximum pwnage.

Comment: I am using shell_exec and the line of code this -> $output = shell_exec("ls -lart"); print_r(''.$output); works fine but if i write the vlc command line it never works like this -> shell_exec(" vlc -I rc \"COMPLETE_URL\" --sout '#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,vb=1024,acodec=mp4a,ab=256}:standard{mux=mp4,dst=/Users/abhishek/Desktop/output451.mp4,access=file}'");  plus how will i stop recording ? this is another issue